# Intuitive image sorting

Tags: files, video, software-rec, images

I have photo collections (consisting of several photo sets each) where all the file names have been randomised and where files have been modified in random order so that sorting them by file name or by date will not help me identify which photos belong together (in a set).  What I would like to be able to do is view all thumbnails like playing cards on a table and move them around freely independently of file name or other sorting criteria.  That way I could group photos that belong together (sets) physically on this virtual table.

Does anybody know a tool that could help me do this?  I have the same problem with video files as well.

Comment: XNview MP have such option (at least under Windows). It create special file in the directory where describe the order changes

Comment: Thanks, Romeo.  XNview MP does the job.  deb-Packages are available on their website: https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use XNview MP which have DEB package.

In the Browser mode you can rearrange the image with drag and drop.